# Advices to handle download file in a NativeScript / TypeScript app for robustness and perfs

Tags: typescript, express, nativescript

I've added the download of a data file to the app through a call of a GET request.

The code seems to work quite well but i'm not confident about robustness and/or perfs.
Any advice **on perfs/robustness only** will be greatly appreciated.

- The file is (and will stay) very small (less than 200kb).
- The connectivity is under wifi.
- The httpserver is an Express/Node.
- The app is a Nativescript 8.3 flavor Typescript.

Code of the Download route (direct from Express sample) :

```
    const download = (req, res) => {
      const fileName = req.params.name;
      res.download(dirRoot + fileName, fileName, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({message: "Echec téléchargement de fichier. " + err,});
          console.log("!!!!!! download, échec envoi du fichier " + dirRoot + fileName);
        }
        else 
          console.log(getCurrentDate() + " Envoi réussi du fichier " + dirRoot + fileName);
      });
    };
```

Code of the app call :

- The file is previously checked if it exists already or not
- global.selfIP contains the IP of the device.
- global.serverIP containts the IP of the server

```
    export async function GetStock():Promise<string>  {
      let result = "";
      if (global.selfIP != "") {
        let serverUrl = "http://" + global.serverIP + ":8080/files/stock.csv";
        await Http.request({url : serverUrl, method : "GET",}).then(
          (response: HttpResponse) => {
            try {
              if ((response.statusCode >= 200) && (response.statusCode <=304)) {
                const resultat   = response.content.toString();
                const chemin     : string = path.join(downloadsPath, 'stock.csv')
                const filefevcsv : File = File.fromPath(chemin);
                filefevcsv.writeTextSync(resultat, WriteOnError, encoding.UTF_8);
              }
              else
                throw Error("Code réponse du serveur : " + response.statusCode);
            }
            catch(err) {
              result = serverUrl + "\nException traitement requete: " + err.message;
            }
          },
          (e) => {
            result = serverUrl + "\nException requete: " + e.message;
          }
        ),
        (error) => {
          result += serverUrl + "\nErreur requête : " + error;
        }
      }
      else 
        result += "Connexion wifi non établie";
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your call in a background task. https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/background-http.html